# How to use JSON result in selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, java, json, selenium-webdriver

Im a beginner for automation testing.Here I want to get the data's from json to be used by selenium webdriver.I wrote one java class and hard coded something to get a result as a try.and getting an answer in console panel like

```
{
  "name": "john",
  "location": "jihu",
  "job": [
    {
      "manager": [
        {
          "collegues": [
            "ram",
              "ranma",
               ],
              }
}
}
```

(not exactly this).

Now i want to use this for one specific application using selenium webdriver. How can i move on with this.help me in detail.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From Selenium and Backend Comparison testing point of view i am answering the same .you need to parse json response using some Libraries like GSON , jackson etc into Java Pojo objects and then apply asserts on the fields you want to compare with json and UI. I guess you need to go through below topics first

1) Serialization -Deserialization API response
2) GSON or Jackson parsers 
3) RestAssured ( Provides framework for API testing )
4) JAVA pojo classed  and usage of them . you might need them to save your response in form of some Response class and compare objects .

Comment: I used this one  , Gson gson = new Gson();  
String myObjName= gson.toJson(myObj);
System.out.println(myObjName); and got that result. After that what should i do...could you tell  me any perfect site for me to get better clarification over this.

Comment: you can Map your response into Map using below code

Comment: Map<Object,Object> map  = gson.fromJson(json.asString(), Map.class); 

now you can play with your map Objects to extract any node you want and compare the same with UI elements using asserts

Comment: Now i just created json file and passed it with by using system. getproperty().Now its working.But Thank you for your information.I try this also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these online converters for converting a json object into Java Pojo Classes : 
http://json2java.azurewebsites.net/   (I usually use this)

https://codebeautify.org/json-to-java-converter

and then place them in a package or in the same class as you wish :

You can better understand it by below example :

```
package com.demo.core;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.response.Response;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String r[]) {
        Response response1 = RestAssured.given().get("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee/1"); // use your method to get the API response (I have used RestAssured here)
        String json = response1.asString(); // you can use your json response here and convert it into a String
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Employee emp = gson.fromJson(json, Employee.class);  // The response is now captured in this Employee class

        System.out.println(emp.getEmployeeAge());
        System.out.println(emp.getEmployeeName());
        System.out.println(emp.getEmployeeSalary());
    }

}

class Employee {
    private String id;
    private String employee_name;
    private String employee_salary;
    private String employee_age;
    private String profile_image;

    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmployeeName() {
        return this.employee_name;
    }

    public void setEmployeeName(String employee_name) {
        this.employee_name = employee_name;
    }

    public String getEmployeeSalary() {
        return this.employee_salary;
    }

    public void setEmployeeSalary(String employee_salary) {
        this.employee_salary = employee_salary;
    }

    public String getEmployeeAge() {
        return this.employee_age;
    }

    public void setEmployeeAge(String employee_age) {
        this.employee_age = employee_age;
    }

    public String getProfileImage() {
        return this.profile_image;
    }

    public void setProfileImage(String profile_image) {
        this.profile_image = profile_image;
    }
}
```

You can easily assert the values after the response is captured in Java classes using their getter methods like I have used in the code to get field values present in Employee class.

Please do let me know if you still got an issue.
If your result contains many fields than better to shift all converted java classes into a separate package for a clear code.

Comment: Thank you for the effort.I try this.